# Initializing page loading browser indicator/animated icon with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there an easy way to start and stop the browser throbber (page loading indicator) without changing the page you are on? Preferably with no external libraries or AJAX calls.

Comment: I've never seen an API for that, but I'd be interested to learn of one. I kind-of seriously doubt it though, especially the ability to turn it off - seems like that'd be a security issue.

Comment: JavaScript has limited (history API modifying the address) to no jurisdiction outside the viewport, unless you give it leverage, like from some plugin or browser extension.

Comment: Hmmm. Good question. Maybe there's another way. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to use the throbber as a loading indicator for CPU-intensive actions in Flash. I do not want to disable the native function of the throbber and would simply like to able to call a method for startThrobber() and stopThrobber() in javascript. Could I possibly do this with a hidden iframe or would this introduce additional problems? Any ideas?

Comment: @William why go through all the hassle? Why not show an animated loading gif instead?

Comment: The throbber indicates that the page is loading data from the network. Using it for anything else would be potentially confusing to the user.

Comment: The UI freezes if something very CPU-intensive is loaded so you never end up seeing the the animated GIF or progress bar. I don't believe any user would see a loading indicator being used for loading as confusing. Consider loading a large set of rows, processing them, and loading them into complex item renderers which may take a few seconds. In my opinion, using the throbber would be appropriate for this situation.

Comment: It seems like this would be a candidate for a new API, so that we can get rid of the zillions of different "Loading..." indicators that applications use. But it doesn't sound like there's a way to do it right now.

Answer (score 12):

No. You could try to force it to spin by performing ajax calls or whatever, but don't. That part of the browser isn't for you, it's for the browser!

This is kinda like asking if you can change the system clock so that your game that includes a time machine is more realistic.

Comment: I am using the throbber to indicate loading which I believe is its intended purpose. For example, if I am calling a web service in Flash the throbber does not appear.

Comment: This is one of the reasons Flash is now considered an out of date technology for the web - it lives in a small rectangle, and can't do much outside of itself due to sandboxing. The browser isn't throbbing, because everything has downloaded. Remember in Chrome for instance, the throbber rotates one way for DNS lookups, and one way for data download - a CPU intensive activity isn't either of those.

Comment: @Rich - This does not answer OP's question in any way, yet it has at this point in time 11 votes up. Funny, but I didn't read anywhere this is a political discussion!! Is it? :confused: Also, out of sheer curiosity, how many different accounts do you have to use as a self-endorsement platform?

Comment: I will consider Flash an out-of-date technology when its entire feature-set is covered by HTML and JS. We are getting close, but still not quite there so Flash will continue to be relevant for particular applications.

Comment: Yes of course. There are many things that can only be done with Flash. It is the correct choice for those things. @TildalWave – not quite sure what you mean: The question was "Is it possible to manually control the browser throbber?". I've answered 'No', then explained why that isn't allowed without performing ajax calls to simulate the behaviour. My comment just above explains in a little more detail why you it's probably a bad idea, and how Flash doesn't really fit into web pages very natively. Nothing particularly controversial here!

Comment: @Rich - This question was tagged under JavaScript, and that changes a bit the meaning of that 'manual control' title to the question, doesn't it? It might be titled a bit clumsy, I give you that, but reading the rest of the question makes it clear what the OP was after, at least it does to me. OP also accepted my answer, and the procedure behind it works in a way that was requested. Should we really go into semantics when the problem presented was solved? I still find your answer misleading as there clearly is a way to achieve what was requested. It also suggests concerns where there aren't.

Comment: What do you think would be a better title for the sake of posterity?

Comment: I guess that I should have answered more like Lie Ryan – the point is that there isn't a native API for doing this, for many good reasons. Flash can't control the browser's chrome, also for good reasons. You can load dummy things via ajax to make the throbber spin, but that's a) specified as a non solution in the question, and b) a hack which I suspect users won't really like. William asked a sensible question, outlined what he didn't want (Ajax calls) and I have answered that by explaining the whys and wherefores. I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: @Rich - There aren't any AJAX calls needed, simple JavaScript will do (as asked in the original question) in conjunction with a server-side script of one's choosing (not AJAX, or depending on any external libraries) that will halt execution for a specified length of time. Thereof, I don't agree with your point a) as being a non-solution to the question asked, and neither with point b) that users might not like something that the author clearly thinks is needed and the solution to is is nearly agnostic to the end user.

Comment: @William - how about "Initializing page loading browser indicator/animated icon with JavaScript"? Something like that should do it, I think most have problems with the mention of 'manual' in your title. Mentioning 'manual' and 'browser' in a single sentence obviously doesn't mix well with most for obvious reasons... adding 'throbber' to it only makes things worse, and mentioning CPU activity in the comments following the question must be almost like adding an insult to injury LOL :D (disclaimer: No, I'm not Jimmy Car!!!)

Answer (score 4):

You could call a simple server side script, let's call it 'sleep.cgi', that would halt execution (sleep) and with it delay the delivery of some simple self-reloading page in a hidden iframe. That should make pretty much any major browsers display what you call a 'browser throbber' (page loading indicator). Once you'd be done with whatever reason you'd want the throbber to display, you would simply reset the mentioned iframe location to an empty string. This is how I'd do it:

1) write a simple server-side script that takes the request and halts the execution for up to 30 seconds, not wanting to hit the browser's page load timeout wall. Once the sleep period is over, this server script responds with something along the lines of:

```
<html><body onload="location.reload();"></body></html>
```

forcing it to loop until you want the browser to display 'page loaded' indicator.

2) write supporting JavaScript functions that will start and stop the 'throbber' on request and add HTML elements we'll be using:

```
<script>
  function startThrobber(){
    document.getElementById('throbberFrame').src='sleep.cgi?'+Math.random();
  }
  function endThrobber(){
    document.getElementById('throbberFrame').src='';
  } 
</script>

<div id="throbberWrapper" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
  <iframe id="throbberFrame" style="width:1px;height:1px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

I've done a quick test in Chrome/IE/Opera/Firefox and it seems to work OK. I've never had any need to do anything like it, though.

EDIT: If your web server supports PHP scripts, here's the sleep function reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php I don't write in PHP but I believe your PHP document should look something along the lines of:

```
<html><body onload="location.reload();">
<?php
  // sleep for 29 seconds
  sleep(29);
?>
</body></html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: @William - Another thing to consider is cache control headers for this  'sleep' script. You might want to disable any browser side cache for it to work properly after 29 seconds. You can achieve this by adding custom cache control headers to your PHP script, or by modifying your web server's configuration to remove any caching headers when this script is requested. For PHP the code would be (with date in the past): header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

Comment: @TildalWave: does this get affected by "too many redirects" detection?

Comment: @Lie - I'm not sure what you mean? There aren't any redirects in this solution per se, only simple loads and reloads. If your question is regarding possible caching problems, then you should note that isn't really a 'problem', even if the page in question doesn't reload completely and the user browser loads cached version. Unless of course you're doing some sort of 'smart' detection to what timeout (sleep) period should be used within the mentioned server-side script. It's not really necessary and I would advise against complicating it anyway, that's why I didn't mention this in the answer. ;)

Comment: Which (Lie's question) kinda reminds me of another thing to consider. If the location of the server-side script passed to the 'throbber' frame will be absolute instead of relative to the path of the caller document, then better avoid adding protocol part to the path not to cause 'mixed content' browser warnings. Basically, if and when a full path is used, just omit the 'http:' or 'https:' part of it and start the location with '//'. This way, the caller document's protocol will be used (attached to the beginning of the provided location) and any unnecessary browser warnings will be avoided. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The UI freezes if something very CPU-intensive is loaded so you never end up seeing the the animated GIF or progress bar.

You have an XY problem. You can prevent the browser from freezing by using setTimeout to divide CPU intensive operations into smaller chunks. The browser throbber is a UI element that signals something is being loaded from the network; it's extremely confusing if you used it for any other reasons.

Comment: How does this answer anything and why is everyone assuming forcing throbber to display would be used for anything else than loading some content. OP clearly describes he'd be using this to indicate loading (albeit of Flash contents) and that is its intended purpose. It has nothing to do with 'UI freezes' either, unless done in a way it really shouldn't be (short loop), which I doubt was OP's intention. Why would he go an extra length to provide users with better indication to what's happening and then create additional problems to these same users for having such a feature?

Comment: @TildalWave: OP have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). He does not really want to control the browser throbber, what he wanted is to indicate progress of a CPU bound process, of which using the browser's throbber is a very user-hostile solution (even if it can be done properly without resorting to a fake ajax call with caching issues and all). OP did indicate the reason he cannot use loading GIF is due to freezing UI, which is really unnecessary in a properly written javascript.

Comment: I really don't see where you get 'CPU bound' from. The 'throbber' OP was referring to is used to indicate to the end user that the document requested (and any subsequent parts of it) is in the process of downloading. It indicates network activity. You're possibly confusing this with the system's hourglass icon. Two not necessarily related things. As for the question formulation, that's just semantics and is to me as relevant as what type of music OP prefers to listen to. The question was understood and answered. Besides, if you don't like the way it was asked, feel free to edit it. ;)

Comment: @TildalWave: check OP's comments, parts of which I quoted. The OP clearly said he wanted to indicate a CPU bound process with the browser throbber. No, I'm not confusing the throbber with the hourglass.

Comment: Ah I see now, that part alluded me, hidden behind 'show more comments' button. Sorry to trouble you! You are indeed correct to say it's rather strange to use one indicator to display activities of another, non-related process. I can still see valid use for what OP asked, though. Might be a strange workaround, but if OP feels it's needed (having a better insight into what he's actually after than we do) then yes, it is possible and I don't see how it could possibly hurt the end user in any way whatsoever either.